# Добрый день столкнулься с проблемой при отпраки cURL PHP

Tags: php, xml, curl, header

```
Отпровляю post запрос через сURL xml .Когда указываю параметр curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml'));или  aplication/xml.Запрос вообще не отпровляется на сервер.Если не узать CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, то xml приходит как массив    [<?xml version="1.0" encoding]"UTF-8" ?>
<priceRequest><customerNo>123</customerNo><password>abc</password><skuList><SKU>.
Как отослать xml чтобы на сервере его согли распарсить .

код

$xml_data = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<priceRequest><customerNo>123</customerNo><password>abc</password><skuList><SKU>99999</SKU><lineNumber>1</lineNumber></skuList></priceRequest>';
$URL = "https://test.testserver.com/PriceAvailability";

$ch = curl_init($URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "$xml_data");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);


print_r($output);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$xml_data = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<priceRequest><customerNo>123</customerNo><password>abc</password><skuList><SKU>99999</SKU><lineNumber>1</lineNumber></skuList></priceRequest>';
$URL = "https://test.testserver.com/PriceAvailability";

$headers = array(
    "Content-type: text/xml",
    "Content-length: " . strlen($xml_data),
    "Connection: close",
);

$ch = curl_init($URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: пробовал уже и в ковычках и без

Comment: @СуртковСтанислав отредактировал ответ, попробуйте так же

Comment: иметирую сервер if($_POST){
      file_put_contents("logs.log", $_POST,FILE_APPEND);
      print_r($_POST);
}
В ответ получаю  "1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<priceRequest><customerNo>123</customerNo><password>abc</password><skuList><SKU>99999</SKU><lineNumber>1</lineNumber></skuList></priceRequest>

Если указываю curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); post не отпровляется

Comment: не помогло ,увас сработало ?

Comment: не чего не получается